# Algorithms for detecting the symmetry group of an object

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

Given a list of points in 3-dimensional space, what's the state-of-the-art in algorithms for calculating the symmetry group ?

Comment: Are you talking about a finite list (or perhaps you mean set) of points? If so, then perhaps this is equivalent to computing the automorphism group of an edge coloured graph, where the colours represent distance between vertices.

Comment: Yes, a finite list of points (eg the list of atom coordinates for a molecule) and the symmetry operations are rotations and reflections. You can always work out some things by inspection, but is there a systematic algorithm ?

Comment: If I am correct, then this reduces to a graph automorphism problem (with coloured edges), for which there are certainly algorithms, and good implementations, such as the Nauty package.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the group that leaves the graph invariant is related to the point group, although it's not clear how to code the direction information in 3-d space (you can assign a weight equal to the Euclidean distance, which can serve as the edge color), or whether the groups will be the same.